# How to use persistent storage on a qemu machine

Tags: qemu

I have compiled a linux ARM image and a root FS using [this](https://medicineyeh.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/buildup-your-arm-image-for-qemu/) guide (used buildroot, not busybox). I am able to run the image successfully with the rootFS. However, if I create a file in /root, it disappears if I quit the machine and run it again. I would like to be able to change the rootFS, e.g., create files and install packages, and I have exhausted googling how to add a --drive or --device for that purpose.
Also, I would like to be able to use the storage to share files btw the host and the guest.

This is the current qemu command line I'm using:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -dtb 
<linux>/arch/arm/boot/dts/vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -kernel 
<linux>/arch/arm/boot/zImage -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sda" 
-initrd ~/buildroot-2018.05/output/images/rootfs.cpio --nographic 
<somedir>/hd0.img
```

where hd0.img was created using qemu-img.

I'd appreciate an answer as well as a deeper explanation to what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vexpress-a9, the only available kind of disk is an emulated SD card. You can set one up with "-drive if=sd,cache=writeback,file=yoursd.img". Note that emulated SD is not very fast. Also you'll need to make sure your guest kernel has the SD controller and SD card support compiled in and that your initrd will mount and pivot to it.

For a QEMU VM with more flexible options (support for more RAM, better performing disk and networking, etc) you should look at the 'virt' board instead. 'vexpress-a9' is only really recommended if you specifically have an image you want to run on an emulation of that devboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you happen to know a good tutorial for setting up a rootfs on a virt board?

Comment: https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2016/11/03/installing-debian-on-qemus-32-bit-arm-virt-board/ describes getting Debian running on 'virt' for 32-bit arm